# May I implement one function of protocol in subclass?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, protocols

I just modified it. Another problem is that if I want to have a subclass inherit from BaseParticipant, may I re-implement `func performEvent` inside the subclass?
For example:

```
class CyclingParticipant: BaseParticipant, Participant
{
init(name: String)
{
    super.init(name: name, preferredEvent: Event.CYCLING)

}

func performEvent(event: Event, distance: Distance) throws
{

}

}
```

but the compiler said "redundant conformance of CyclingParticipant to protocol Participant .

```
class BaseParticipant: Participant
{
 var name: String
 var preferredEvent: Event
 var raceTime: Int
 var couldNotFinish: Bool
 //var performedEvent: Event
// in swift, the class accepts protocol must impletment all funcs inside protocol

init(name: String, preferredEvent: Event)
{
    self.name = name
    self.preferredEvent = preferredEvent
    self.raceTime = 0
    self.couldNotFinish = false
}

func getName() -> String
{
    return self.name
}

func getPreferredEvent() -> Event
{
    return self.preferredEvent
}

func isDisqualified() -> Bool
{
    return self.couldNotFinish
}

func addTime(addtionalRaceTime:Int) -> Void
{
    self.raceTime += addtionalRaceTime
}

func setCouldNotFinish() -> Void
{
    self.couldNotFinish = true
}
func performEvent(event: Event, distance: Distance) throws -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func getTime() throws
{

}

}
```

The code of protocol Participant:

```
protocol Participant
{
func getName() -> String
func getPreferredEvent() -> Event
func isDisqualified() -> Bool
func performEvent(event: Event,distance: Distance) throws ->Int
func addTime(addtionalRaceTime: Int)
func setCouldNotFinish()
func getTime() throws

}
```

Comment: where is `getTime()` implemented? `performEvent()` does neither return an Int, nor throw.

Comment: `getTime()` is not the same as `addTime()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an implementation of the `getTime()` function as listed in your Protocol.  Also, you should post such questions on Piazza. :P

[Updating to answer reworded question]

The `BaseParticipant` class already adopts the `Participant` protocol, so the `CyclingParticipant` subclass should not declare that it adopts it also, this is causing the redundant conformance error.  Because `BaseParticipant` is already a `Participant`, any subclass of `BaseParticipant` will also be a `Participant`.

Change:

```
class CyclingParticipant: BaseParticipant, Participant
```

to:

```
class CyclingParticipant: BaseParticipant
```

Comment: I thought since you are a full-time employee outside the campus, maybe you will be very busy after class....

Comment: We all use stack overflow. :D

Comment: I cannot re-implement a function belongs to protocol in a subclass,like my updates. Can we re-implement it in swift?

Comment: You'll have to implement all protocol methods in the base class.  You cannot make a class `abstract` in Swift like you can in Java.  You can override functions in subclasses, but you cannot declare that the subclass also adopts the protocol, this is the error it is giving you.

Answer (score 1):

All declared methods in a Swift protocol are required by default.

`getTime()` is not implemented